# Is there an eConnect for Microsoft Dynamics GP 8

Tags: vb6, dynamics-gp

I have a question regarding eConnet does GP8 already have this, if it does can I use Visual Basic 6 as a tool to integrate system to GP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, eConnect is available for GP 8.

You can develop an eConnect integration by either using the SQL Stored Procedures directly or with the SDK and any .NET language.

Unfortunately that means that it is not possible to use Visual Basic 6. However if you are familiar with Visual Basic 6 then learning the syntax of Visual Basic .NET should be easy.

The eConnect SDK and installation package may be obtained from Microsoft Customer Source or a through a Microsoft Dynamics GP Partner.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in a fully integrated solution for GP with POS and eCommerce systems. [nChannel](http://www.nchannel.com/connect-microsoft-dynamics-gp-2/) provides this type of integration for Dynamics GP users.